# Java libGDX Game - Animation doesn't flip

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx, game-engine

I have a animation which i want to flip to the left if key LEFT is pressed, but it doesnt stay flipped. It only flips like 1 frame then turns back again.

Here is my GameScreen where i draw everything:

```
public class GameScreen extends ScreenManager{
    //For the view of the game and the rendering
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;

    //DEBUG
    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;

    //World, Player and so on
    private GameWorld world;
    private Player player;
    private Ground ground;

    //player animations
    private TextureRegion currFrame;

    public static float w, h;

    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);
        //vars
        w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        //view and rendering
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, w/2, h/2);

        //debug
        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        //world, bodies ...
        world = new GameWorld();
        player = new Player(world);
        ground = new Ground(world);

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {


    }

    @Override
    public void show() {


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        //clearing the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //updating
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        player.stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        //render
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        currFrame = Player.anim.getKeyFrame(Player.stateTime, true);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(currFrame, Player.body.getPosition().x * PPM - 64, Player.getBody().getPosition().y * PPM-  72);
        batch.end();

        //debug
        b2dr.render(GameWorld.getWorld(), cam.combined.scl(PPM));   


    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {


    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {


    }


    @Override
    public void dispose() {


    }

    @Override
    public void onKlick(float delta) {


    }

    public void update(float delta){
        world.update(delta);
        updateCam(delta);
        Player.keyInput(delta);
        System.out.println("X-POS" + Player.getBody().getPosition().x);
        System.out.println("Y-POS" + Player.getBody().getPosition().y);
    }

    public void updateCam(float delta){
        Vector3 pos = cam.position;
        pos.x = Player.getBody().getPosition().x * PPM;
        pos.y = Player.getBody().getPosition().y * PPM;

        cam.position.set(pos);

        cam.update();
    }



}
```

and this is the Player class where the animation is:

```
public class Player {
    public static Body body;
    public static BodyDef def;
    private FixtureDef fd;

    //textures
    public static Texture texture;
    public static Sprite sprite;
    public static TextureRegion[][] region;
    public static TextureRegion[] idle;
    public static Animation<TextureRegion> anim;
    public static float stateTime;

    //set form
    private PolygonShape shape;

    private GameScreen gs;

    public Player(GameWorld world){
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("player/char_animation_standing.png"));
        region = TextureRegion.split(texture, texture.getWidth() / 3, texture.getHeight() / 2);
        idle = new TextureRegion[6];
        int index = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                sprite = new Sprite(region[i][j]);
                idle[index++] = sprite;
            }
        }

        anim = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1 / 8f, idle);

        stateTime = 0f;

        def = new BodyDef();
        def.fixedRotation = true;
        def.position.set(gs.w / 4, gs.h / 4);
        def.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

        body = world.getWorld().createBody(def);

        shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(32 / 2 / PPM, 64/ 2 / PPM);

        fd = new FixtureDef();
        fd.shape = shape;
        fd.density = 30;

        body.createFixture(fd);
        shape.dispose();
    }

    public static Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public static BodyDef getDef() {
        return def;
    }



    public static Texture getTexture() {
        return texture;
    }

    public static void keyInput(float delta){
        int horizonForce = 0;
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP)){
            body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 300f, body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, true);
            //body.applyForceToCenter(0, 1200f, true);
            System.out.println("PRESSED");
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)){
            horizonForce -= 1;
            sprite.flip(!sprite.isFlipX(), sprite.isFlipY());
        }

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)){
            horizonForce += 1;
        }

        body.setLinearVelocity(horizonForce * 20, body.getLinearVelocity().y);
    }



}
```

thank you in advance and any answer is appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sprite variable contain only one frame at the time of pressing left key. So, it flip that current sprite of your animation frame. 
To solve the Problem you have to flip all the animation frame on pressing the left key.

Comment: If it solve your problem then please accept it as right answer of your question.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to I get the Player to jump only once?

Comment: [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50969/implementing-a-basic-jump-in-libgdx)

Comment: [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121386/how-to-jump-in-box2d-with-libgdx)

Answer (score 1):

You're only flipping last frame of Animation by `sprite` reference, You need to flip all frames of your `Animation` `anim`. You can flip in this way :

```
if(keycode== Input.Keys.RIGHT) {

    for (TextureRegion textureRegion:anim.getKeyFrames())
        if(!textureRegion.isFlipX()) textureRegion.flip(true,false);
}
else if(keycode==Input.Keys.LEFT) {

    for (TextureRegion textureRegion:anim.getKeyFrames())
       if(textureRegion.isFlipX()) textureRegion.flip(true,false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you too for your answer!